# I'm adding 2 markers on google map.I have to show different custom info windows for two markers, how can I do that in android

Tags: android

Here is my sample code am trying to add two markers. I'm adding 2 markers on google map.I have to show different custom info windows for two markers, how can I do that in android?

Below is the code written for that

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(position).title(v_nam)
                                            .snippet(v_loc)
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))).showInfoWindow();
                                    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                                            return null;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                                            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
                                            String t1 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Vehicle :</font>";
                                            String t2 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Vehicle Type :</font>";
                                            String t4 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Speed :</font>";
                                            String t5 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Location Address :</font>";
                                            String t6 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Ignition :</font>";
                                            String t7 = "<font color='#0000FF'>  Live Date And Time :</font>";

                                            TextView tvV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_vehicle);
                                            tvV.setText(Html.fromHtml(t1 + v_nam));

                                            TextView tvVT = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_vehicletype);
                                            tvVT.setText(Html.fromHtml(t2 + v_vt));

                                            TextView tvDt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_dateandtime);
                                            tvDt.setText(Html.fromHtml(t7 + v_ld));

                                            TextView tvLoc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
                                            tvLoc.setText(Html.fromHtml(t5 + v_loc));

                                            TextView tvSped = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_direction);
                                            tvSped.setText(Html.fromHtml(t4 + v_dir));

                                            TextView tvign = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ignition);
                                            tvign.setText(Html.fromHtml(t6 + v_ig));
                                            return v;
                                        }
                                    });

                                    mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position , 13.0f) );
                                }
                                drawPolyLineOnMap(Points);
                                Log.i("history la", String.valueOf(Points));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag your marker and use it in getInfoContents() method.

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.getTag() == YOUR_FIRST_MARKER_TAG) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents_FOR_FIRST_MARKER, null);
            //MORE CODE
            return v;
        } else {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents_FOR_SECOND_MARKER, null);
            //MORE CODE
            return v;
        }
    }
```